# Hibernate Criteria - Excluding group by clause in the select statement

Tags: java, hibernate

I've written this in sql server:

```
select max(processed_trans_id) from EQUITY_TRANSACTION where transaction_date <= '2016-06-22' and company_id=75 group by comp_acct_id
```

But when I try to write the same in Hibernate Criteria, like this:

```
DetachedCriteria dCriteria = DetachedCriteria.forClass(EquityTransaction.class)
            .add(Restrictions.eq("clientCompany.id", sb.getClientCompany().getId()))
            .add(Restrictions.le("transactionDate", sb.getQualifyDate()))
            .setProjection(Projections.projectionList()
                    .add(Projections.max("processedTransaction.id"), "processedTransaction.id")
                    .add(Projections.groupProperty("holderCompanyAccount.id")));
```

I get this as the sql query from hibernate:

```
select max(processed_trans_id), comp_acct_id from EQUITY_TRANSACTION where transaction_date <= '2016-06-22' and company_id=75 group by comp_acct_id
```

How do I replicate the original SQL query in Hibernate criteria?

Comment: every column of group by clause should be in select so hibernate adding `comp_acct_id` in select clause

Comment: well, obviously, that's not entirely true, considering The sql statement without the column in the select clause is very much valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this using the following query. Worked like a charm!

```
DetachedCriteria dCriteriaEt1 = DetachedCriteria.forClass(EquityTransaction.class, "et1")
                    .add(Restrictions.eq("clientCompany.id", decldDvd.getClientCompany().getId()))
                    .add(Restrictions.le("transactionDate", decldDvd.getQualifyDate()))
                    .setProjection(Projections.projectionList()
                            .add(Projections.max("processedTransaction.id"), "processedTransaction.id"))
                    .add(Restrictions.eqProperty("et1.holderCompanyAccount.id", "et2.holderCompanyAccount.id"));

            logger.info("Retrieving all qualified company account balances...");
            Criteria getQualifiedBalances = dao.getSession().createCriteria(EquityTransaction.class, "et2")
                    .add(Subqueries.propertyIn("processedTransaction.id", dCriteriaEt1))
                    .add(Restrictions.gt("balance", 0l))
                    .setProjection(Projections.projectionList()
                            .add(Projections.property("holderCompanyAccount.id"),"holderCompanyAccount.id")
                            .add(Projections.property("balance"), "balance"))
                    .addOrder(Order.asc("holderCompanyAccount.id"))
                    .addOrder(Order.desc("processedTransaction.id"))
                    .setResultTransformer(new AliasToBeanNestedResultTransformer(EquityTransaction.class));
```